# What are these minifigures?

Tags: minifigure-identification

Does someone know what theme or set these minifigures are from?

[image]

Comment: Hi Brick Adventures, welcome to Bricks.SE.  It looks like Alex has answered this.  If you agree it is our custom in StackExchange-land to click the checkbox by the answer to indicate that you have accepted it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First one is [Ultron Sentry](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sh166) from [Iron Man vs. Ultron (76029)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76029-1) set.

[image]

Second is a minifigure made with torso and legs from [Duros Alliance Fighter, Jet Pack](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sw0689), [Minifigure, Headgear Helmet SW Hoth Rebel Trooper](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87555&idColor=69#T=C&C=69), [Minifigure, Visor Snow Goggles](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=46304&idColor=1#T=C&C=1) and unknown head. All come in [Rebel Alliance Battle Pack (75133)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75133-1) most likely since it contains all parts and similar head piece seen in your picture.

[image] [image] [image]

Last one is [Aaron - Flat Silver Visor, Clip, Curved Slope and Tow Ball on Back](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=nex004), without the slope and tow ball on the back it seems. It is from [Moltor's Lava Smasher (70313)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70313-1)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The third one is Aaron from Nexo Knights. The first is an Avengers character. The second is likely Star Wars.